# How to use creators in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

In the `ConstraintLayout` we have new type of param `creator`: `layout_constraintTop_creator` or `layout_constraintRight_creator`
How it should be used?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As the namespace implies (`tools:layout_constraintTop_creator`), it's purely used by Android Studio -- those attributes (using the namespace `tool`) are actually stripped out when the xml file is pushed on a device.

So it shouldn't be used :)

Now if you want to know how Studio use those, it's actually simple: we use the creator attributes to keep track of who created the constraints, particularly if they are created by the inference engine, as we want to scrap them / replace them in some cases.

Comment: What are the different values?  For example is a value of "1" the inference engine?

Comment: Now (1.0.2) creator attribute is in `app` name space too.. What would that mean?